# CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ZipArchive' could not be found but dll is in GAC

Tags: asp.net, dll, gac

This error has many questions on SO, but with me the problem is not on the development machine in VisualStudio 2017, but on the deployment machine. Both machines have .Net 4.5 installed. The project is .Net 4.5. The references in the project are OK, I can use the `ZipArchive` class just fine for testing.

In the source code I have a

```
using System.IO.Compression;//GZipStream, ZipArchive
```

On both machines, I have located the 3 dll's for System.IO.Compression, not in C:\Windows\assembly, but in the directories like this which should be OK:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.Compression\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089`

In web.config there is a line:

```
<add assembly="System.IO.Compression, Version=4.0.0.0, 
     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

In the website project properties page I see a reference to

```
 System.IO.Compression    GAC    4.0.0.0
```

On the production machine, in IIS, the application pool in on .Net v4.0.

On that machine, in Internet Explorer, under 'detailed compiler output', I see lots of options referring to the directory path above, e.g.:

```
/R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\
              v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" 

/R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Services\
                v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Services.dll"
```

So why can I use the ZipArchive class on the development machine but am I getting a `could not find` error on the deployment machine, and how to fix this? Please help

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem by moving the dependency away from the Web Site project to a Class Library project. Would still be nice to know why this was necessary, though.